# What can't IntelliJ do that other JetBrains IDE's can?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I was just wondering what unique features other JetBrains IDE's offer that IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate cannot offer (even with plugins). For example, I know it is impossible to get C/C++ support in IDEA right now (at least good support). However, looking at tools like DataGrip and the new Rider IDE, it's not very clear if IntelliJ encapsulates all of these features.

Comment: If I give you a kind of a general answer, since your question is somewhat broad, all Jetbrains IDEs use same core implementation. So any general tools like editor tools, navigation tools etc. wont be different at all. But since there are different Jetbrains IDE's specialized in different languages, there might be language specific tools dropped in other IDEs w.r.t. the specialized IDE for that. :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of large feature areas, AppCode, CLion and Rider are separate products which aren't available as plugins for IntelliJ IDEA. DataGrip's functionality is available out of the box in IntelliJ Ultimate.

There are also lots of smaller differences in the user interface (mainly around project setup), because each language-specific IDE is optimized for the workflows used in the community of users of that language.